# Can't bind to 'rangePicker' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-date-range-input' & 'mat-date-range-input' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material

I installed Angular Material datepicker in my project and used date range picker and got the following error:

```
    compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'rangePicker' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-date-range-input'.
1. If 'mat-date-range-input' is an Angular component and it has 'rangePicker' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-date-range-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
                <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [ERROR ->][rangePicker]="picker">
                    <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="): ng:///AppModule/UploadPostComponent.html@40:58
'mat-date-range-input' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-date-range-input' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-date-range-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("       <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
                [ERROR ->]<mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
                    <input matStar"): ng:///AppModule/UploadPostComponent.html@40:16
'mat-date-range-picker' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-date-range-picker' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-date-range-picker' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                [ERROR ->]<mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>

                <mat-error *ngIf="range.co"): ng:///AppModule/UploadPostComponent.html@45:16
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:11388)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25963)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25951)
    at compiler.js:25895
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:25895)
    at compiler.js:25808
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2166)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25807)
```

I have seen in the forum and in several other sources that the use of mat-date-range-picker only works from version 10.
I updated my version and I still get the same error

This is my module code:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
  
imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
 ],
```

Does anyone have an answer for me?
Thanks.

Comment: has you import `{MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';`?

Comment: Yes, I probably missed ... I fixed.